# HTTPS global load balancer does not seem to work for a subdomain in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am exploring how I can create an application on Cloud Run and then use a Global HTTPs Classic load balancer to manage traffic across different Cloud Run instances. I have create a simple cloud run application with demo Cloud Run image.

I have used the below configuration for my load balancer

[image: Load Balancer configuration]

**Domain: sidharthvijayakumar.fun**

**subdomain: python.sidharthvijayakumar.fun**

I have purchased a domain from Hostinger and currently using CloudFlare to manage the ssl/tls certificate by changing the Nameserver in Hostinger. I have created a A record for the sub domain

[image: A record for subdomain]

I have enabled the ssl/tls in Cloudflare as well and then created a SSL certificate which is of flexible type(encryption from browser to Cloudflare)

Now using the CA and the privet key I have created a tls certificate in GCP load balancer and it seems to look fine.

[image: TLS certificate added on the load balancer]

Expectation: Now when I hit the subdomain I expect it to show the response of my Cloud Run application

[image: Expected response when I hit the load balancer URL(Subdomain: python.sidharthvijayakumar.fun)]

Actual response: But when I hit the subdomain I get a hostinger page which is something that I do not want to see.

[image: unexpected response on hitting the subdomain]

Can someone guide me how I can get the GCP Cloud Run output on my subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved the major mistake which I did was I did not point the A record to the right IPv4.

In this solution I generated the SSL certificate(full strict mode) and then generated a origin certificate for the domain : **demo.sidharthvijayakumar.fun**

Once this was done I had reserved a static IP for my load balancer. I created an A record for subdomain demo.sidharthvijayakumar.fun and used the static IP.

[image: Added the A record]

Once this was done I cleared the cache of browser and from Cloudflare and things started working.

[image: subdomain gave the expected response]